# How to open a new record in MS Access after required fields have been completed

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a form in Access where I have a series of required fields. Once all of the required fields have been completed and the user clicks a button called Add New Record, I need the form to refresh so they can enter new data. I've created this form by using snipits I've found on Stackoverflow. For the most part the form does what I need it to do. (It checks for missing fields, displays error is fields are correct) The piece I'm missing is is won't refresh the page. It's not displaying any errors. Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated. Below is the code I'm currently using.

Thank you

```
Private Function CheckAllFields() As Boolean
Dim Ctrl As Control
CheckAllFields = False
For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
 If Ctrl.Tag = "*" And IsNull(Ctrl) Then
            MsgBox "Please complete ALL required fields"
    CheckAllFields = True
    Exit For
 End If
Next Ctrl
End Function

Private Sub New_Record_Click()
If CheckAllFields = True Then Exit Sub

If PYMT_AMT < AMT_RECOVERED And CONSOLIDATED_CK = "NO" Then
MsgBox "CONSOLIDATED CHECK ERROR" & vbCrLf & _
        "The Amount Recovered is greater than the Exception Amount." & vbCrLf & _
        " Please confirm answer to Consolidated Check question"

End If

If PYMT_AMT > AMT_RECOVERED And CONSOLIDATED_CK = "YES" Then
MsgBox "CONSOLIDATED CHECK ERROR" & vbCrLf & _
        "The Amount Recovered is less than the Exception Amount." & vbCrLf & _
        " Please confirm answer to Consolidated Check question"

End If

If PYMT_AMT > AMT_RECOVERED And PARTIAL_RECOVERY = "NO" Then
MsgBox "PARTIAL RECOVERY ERROR" & vbCrLf & _
    "The Amount Recovered is less than the Exception Amount." & vbCrLf & _
        " Please confirm answer to Partial Recovery question."

End If

If PYMT_AMT < AMT_RECOVERED And PARTIAL_RECOVERY = "YES" Then
MsgBox "PARTIAL RECOVERY ERROR" & vbCrLf & _
    "The Amount Recovered is greater than the Exception Amount." & vbCrLf & _
        " Please confirm answer to Partial Recovery question."

End If

If RECOVERY_TYP = "Check Payable to Fiserv" And CHECK_NUM = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter check number." & vbCrLf & _
        " AND Please confirm answer to Partial Recovery question."

End If

If Me.RECOVERY_TYP = "Check Payable to Fiserv" Then
If IsNull(Me.CHECK_NUM) Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Check Number"
Cancel = True
Me.CHECK_NUM.SetFocus
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just add:

Me.DataEntry =True

...before your "End Sub".

Comment: Sort of worked. I entered information into the form so it would populate the error messages. When I click OK to acknowledge the error message, the form refreshed without allowing me to fix the mistakes.

Comment: So what the Me.DataEntry=True 'appears' to have accomplished is that it refreshed the page once all of the required fields had 'something' in them but it didn't cycle back through to check the fields for accuracy based on the various IF statements. I'll keep researching this.

Comment: Then instead of using "Me.DataEntry =True", use "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSave"

Comment: I replaced the Me.DataEntry command with the DoCmd as suggested. The form is acting like it originally did.. It will perform all of the checks and balances to 1) make sure all of the 'required' fields have been completed and 2) verify the accuracy of certain fields.. However, when I click the button, it does not clear the form fields like I need it to.

Comment: I replaced the Me.DataEntry command with the DoCmd as suggested. The form will checks to make sure all of the 'required' fields have been completed and verify the accuracy of certain fields.. However, when I click the button, it does not clear the form fields like I need it to.

I tried a different approach where I added a SAVE button that has all of the validation code in it and then changed the Add New Record button to just go to a new record. My concern is someone COULD partially complete the form and click the Add New Record button and be presented with a blank form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your form is bound to a table, but if so, once you have ensured that the existing form data was validated and persisted, could you not just add the below line to your code? This should bring you to a new table record with the form fields empty.

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Your Form Name", acNewRec
```